# How can I categorize my videos?

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920

I have a lot of educational videos.

Right now it shows them in a huge list, which is hard to browse. How can I organize them to make them easier to browse? Is there a way to make categories, catalogs, playlists, or something similar? I'm open to using an alternative for video playing.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can have only one option that to make an ordered list of files. Rename your video titles as in which order that you want to categorize like

- `1-video.mp4`
- `2-video.avi`
- `3.video1.mp4`

.There might be third party video players but can play videos only from external memory.